# Java: JSON.simple Parser - convert BufferedReader's readUTF string to Reader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, datainputstream, json-simple

I am writing a server which receives a JSON string then parse it to Java `JSONObject`, by using the JSON.simple package: https://mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/.

I am using DataInputStream to read input, but when I try to parse the input by writing:

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(input.readUTF());
```

it says that `parse(Java.io.Reader) can not be applied to (Java.lang.String)`. SO how do I convert the `input.readUTF()`into the required `reader` format?

For reference, my code for receiving and parsing the JSON input:

```
    public class ReceiveThread implements Runnable{
        private DataInputStream input;

        public ReceiveThread(DataInputStream input){
            this.input = input;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            while (true){
                String res = null;
                try {
                    if (input.available() > 0){
                        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(input.readUTF());
                        System.out.println("Server response: "+ res);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

At the client side, I send the JSON file by:

```
    public class SendThread implements Runnable{
        private DataOutputStream output;

        public SendThread(DataOutputStream output){
            this.output = output;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // create json string
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("key1", 1);
            json.put("key2", "Helloworld");

            try {
                this.output.writeUTF(json.toString());
                this.output.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance! Any bits of help is appreciated.

Yige

Comment: Can you share the json that you are trying to parse

Comment: @sanjeevRm Yes! Please see the updated post.

Comment: Is your project for learning purposes?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yes. This is a school project

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be the version problem with JSON.simple.

In v1.1, the `parse` method takes the `reader` argument, but in version 1.1.1 `parse` is able to take `String` arguments.